# Compilation problem fontenc-Latex

Tags: compiling, font-encodings

When i compile with LaTex the file

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

i'v got this message error in the log file :

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=latex 2019.5.6) 16 FEB 2020 12:58
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**Test.tex
(./Test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.115 \xdef\@fontenc@load@list{\@fontenc@load@list
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
) (./Test.aux
Package babel Warning: Unknown language `french'. Very likely you
(babel) requested it in a previous run. Expect some
(babel) wrong results in this run, which should vanish
(babel) in the next one. Reported on input line 7.
)
\openout1 = `Test.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
[1
] (./Test.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
446 strings out of 492617
4272 string characters out of 6129493
60801 words of memory out of 5000000
4442 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
4702 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
22i,4n,19p,145b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
Output written on Test.dvi (1 page, 228 bytes).
```

The compilation with pdfLaTeX works fine.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: show more of your log, it looks like you have an inconsistent installation with some files from the latest `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2` release and some older ones. But a log would show the full paths of files used

Comment: This happens very recently.

Comment: yes the PL2 release was a few days ago, but you have somehow not got a full update. your latex format is very old `LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>` that is despite having updated to the 2020 sources your latex format is still from 2018 and not compatibile, as fontenc package is tied to the format it is distributed with.  You must have a local setup preventing the latex format being built.  try `fmtutil-sys --all`

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: you need to give more clues than "it doesn't work" this is a local customisation issue on your machine, so it is hard to help unless you debug. You have the _sources_ for the latest release but your latex format is not built from those sources.

Comment: so does `pdflatex '\stop'`  report `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2` but `latex '\stop'` report  `LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>` ?

Comment: what do `kpsewhich -engine=pdftex latex.fmt` and `kpsewhich -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt`   report ?

Comment: I had the same problem. It was resolved by @DavidCarlisle's suggestion to run ´fmtutil-sys --all´. I have no idea why my installation had gotten into this state.

Comment: Same problem here: `pdflatex` and `xelatex` both reported `LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2`, but `latex` and `lualatex` reported `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3`.

It seems stuff got cached under my home directory, for some reason; after removing that redundant `texmf-var` hierarchy and rerunning `fmtutil-sys --all`, the problem disappeared :

`kpsewhich -engine=pdftex latex.fmt` → `~/Library/texlive/2019/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt` but
`kpsewhich -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` → `/opt/texlive/2019/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`

Comment: I too had this issue and @DavidCarlisle's comment fixed it for me as well. I had not done anything funky, that I am aware of. All I do from time to time is a `tlmgr update --all`. If you post it as an actual answer, I can give you a proper upvote :)

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but just where should I 'use' fmtutil-sys --all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that while you have the latest sources (from `tlmgr update`) the format files were not rebuilt using those sources.

```
fmtutil-sys --all
```

will rebuild the format files in texlive.

Comment: I use the solution proposed by Damien and yours. It works fine. Thanks a lot !