# Compilation problem with fontenc-Latex - LaTeX2e problem

Tags: r, rstudio

Unfortunately, I am experiencing the same issue as reported in [Compilation problem fontenc-Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528671/compilation-problem-fontenc-latex). I reinstalled my TeX installation and ran `tlmgr update`, all to no avail. I am using RStudio Version 1.3.820 (but also experience the same issue in RStudio Version 1.2.5033), with updates of all packages. I suspect the error lies in the use of an old `LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>` version, but I have no clue, why this version would be used, even though I have reinstalled my TeX installation with all sorts of different repositories.

I noticed that no matter what repository I use I get the following errors:

```
tlmgr install: package ifluatex not present in repository.
tlmgr install: package ifxetex not present in repository.
```

Am I right to suspect that this might cause the problem? Any suggestions how I could fix this? Again, running `tlmgr update --all --self` does not report any error or need to update.

When knitting my text in RStudio I get the following log:

```
/usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS MODE_proposal_APA.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash+raw_attribute --output MODE_proposal_APA.tex --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --include-in-header /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/papaja/rmarkdown/templates/apa6/resources/apa6_header_includes.tex --variable graphics --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua --wrap preserve --csl /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/papaja/rmd/apa6.csl --filter /usr/local/bin/pandoc-citeproc --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rmdfiltr/replace_ampersands.lua --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/rmdfiltr/wordcount.lua --variable 'classoption:,doc,a4paper' --variable 'lang:en-US' --variable 'subparagraph:yes' --variable 'block-headings:no' --include-in-header /var/folders/hh/vy5948dx2jv2v9qc_m2tbrx00000gn/T//Rtmp9tAYmU/includes_14464266266e.tex 
output file: MODE_proposal_APA.knit.md


! Undefined control sequence.
l.115 \xdef\@fontenc@load@list{\@fontenc@load@list
```

None of my documents render anymore. So using a different class makes no difference. I would very much appreciate any suggestions how to tackle this, since simply running `tlmgr update` did not solve it. (Sorry for posting this in an answer previously).

Here's the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.5.12)  21 FEB 2020 12:07
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**MODE_proposal_APA.tex
(./MODE_proposal_APA.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/apa7/apa7.cls
Document Class: apa7 2019/12/30 v1.04 APA formatting (7th edition)
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count88
)
Class apa7 Info: No bibliography package was specified; defaulting to (but not 
loading) Biblatex on input line 218.
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
) (/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX package
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2020/02/11 v2.0o Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmr on input line 112.
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.115 \xdef\@fontenc@load@list{\@fontenc@load@list

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 865 strings out of 494553
 9932 string characters out of 6176313
 67509 words of memory out of 5000000
 4605 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 6930 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 33i,0n,29p,804b,76s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

As requested the output of `fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdflatex`

```
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehypht-
x-2019-04-04.pat
German Hyphenation Patterns (Traditional Orthography) `dehypht-x' 2019-04-04 (W
L)))
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehyphn-
x-2019-04-04.tex dehyph-exptl: using an 8-bit TeX engine.
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehyphn-
x-2019-04-04.pat
German Hyphenation Patterns (Reformed Orthography, 2006) `dehyphn-x' 2019-04-04
 (WL)))) (/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu))
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltexpl.ltx
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.ltx
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex

(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3deprecation.
def))))
 ) )
Beginning to dump on file pdflatex.fmt
 (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.2.21)
16842 strings of total length 286120
230907 memory locations dumped; current usage is 165&224195
15135 multiletter control sequences
\font\nullfont=nullfont
\font\OMX/cmex/m/n/10=cmex10
\font\tenln=line10
\font\tenlnw=linew10
\font\tencirc=lcircle10
\font\tencircw=lcirclew10
\font\OT1/cmr/m/n/5=cmr5
\font\OT1/cmr/m/n/7=cmr7
\font\OT1/cmr/m/n/10=cmr10
\font\OML/cmm/m/it/5=cmmi5
\font\OML/cmm/m/it/7=cmmi7
\font\OML/cmm/m/it/10=cmmi10
\font\OMS/cmsy/m/n/5=cmsy5
\font\OMS/cmsy/m/n/7=cmsy7
\font\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10=cmsy10
\font\c__fp_exp_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00002pt
\font\c__fp_trig_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00003pt
\font\g__regex_charcode_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00005pt
\font\g__regex_catcode_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00006pt
\font\g__regex_balance_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00008pt
\font\g__regex_state_active_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00009pt
\font\g__regex_thread_state_intarray=cmr10 at 0.0001pt
\font\g__regex_submatch_prev_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00012pt
\font\g__regex_submatch_begin_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00014pt
\font\g__regex_submatch_end_intarray=cmr10 at 0.00015pt
532331 words of font info for 24 preloaded fonts
14 hyphenation exceptions
Hyphenation trie of length 67075 has 1136 ops out of 35111
  475 for language 4
  478 for language 3
  2 for language 1
  181 for language 0
0 words of pdfTeX memory
0 indirect objects
No pages of output.
Transcript written on pdflatex.log.
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt installed.
fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking pdfetex with pdftex
fmtutil: running `pdftex -ini   -jobname=pdfetex -progname=pdfetex -translate-file=cp227.tcx *pdfetex.ini' ...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (INITEX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 (/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/web2c/cp227.tcx)
entering extended mode
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/plain/config/pdfetex.ini
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/pdftexc
onfig.tex)
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/plain/etex/etex.src
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/plain.tex
Preloading the plain format: codes, registers, parameters, fonts, more fonts,
macros, math definitions, output routines, hyphenation
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex
[skipping from \patterns to end-of-file...]))
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/plain/etex/etexdefs.lib
Skipping module "grouptypes"; Loading module "interactionmodes";
Skipping module "nodetypes"; Skipping module "iftypes";)
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.def
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyphen/hyphen.tex)
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehypht-
x-2019-04-04.tex dehyph-exptl: using an 8-bit TeX engine.
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehypht-
x-2019-04-04.pat
German Hyphenation Patterns (Traditional Orthography) `dehypht-x' 2019-04-04 (W
L)))
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehypht-
x-2019-04-04.tex dehyph-exptl: using an 8-bit TeX engine.
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehypht-
x-2019-04-04.pat
German Hyphenation Patterns (Traditional Orthography) `dehypht-x' 2019-04-04 (W
L)))
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehyphn-
x-2019-04-04.tex dehyph-exptl: using an 8-bit TeX engine.
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehyphn-
x-2019-04-04.pat
German Hyphenation Patterns (Reformed Orthography, 2006) `dehyphn-x' 2019-04-04
 (WL)))
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehyphn-
x-2019-04-04.tex dehyph-exptl: using an 8-bit TeX engine.
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl/dehyphn-
x-2019-04-04.pat
German Hyphenation Patterns (Reformed Orthography, 2006) `dehyphn-x' 2019-04-04
 (WL)))) Augmenting the Plain TeX definitions: \tracingall;
Adding new e-TeX definitions: \eTeX, \loggingall, \tracingnone,
register allocation; extended register allocation; 
Recycling: \addlanguage, \@nswer (not defined), \@sk, \b@dresponsetrue,
\b@dresponsefalse, \ch@ckforyn, \mayber@cycle, \et@xabort, \et@xbuf,
\et@xfmtsrc, \et@xfilehdr, \et@xinf, \et@xpatterns, \l@ngdefnfile, \n@xt,
\p@rse (not defined), \pr@mpt (not defined), \pr@mptloop (not defined),
\forcer@cycle, \usef@llback, \usef@llbacktrue, \usef@llbackfalse, 
Retaining: \et@xerr, \et@xinput, \et@xlibhdr, \et@xmsg, \et@xtoks, \et@xwarn,
\et@xl@@d, \et@xl@ad, \et@xload, \et@xlang, \et@xhash, \eTeX, \etexhdrchk,
\etexstatus, \module, \uselanguage, \r@tain, \r@cycle,)
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/plain/config/pdftexmagfix.tex
) )
Beginning to dump on file pdfetex.fmt
 (preloaded format=pdfetex 2020.2.21)
2939 strings of total length 45509
8034 memory locations dumped; current usage is 203&7395
1282 multiletter control sequences
\font\nullfont=nullfont
\font\tenrm=cmr10
\font\preloaded=cmr9
\font\preloaded=cmr8
\font\sevenrm=cmr7
\font\preloaded=cmr6
\font\fiverm=cmr5
\font\teni=cmmi10
\font\preloaded=cmmi9
\font\preloaded=cmmi8
\font\seveni=cmmi7
\font\preloaded=cmmi6
\font\fivei=cmmi5
\font\tensy=cmsy10
\font\preloaded=cmsy9
\font\preloaded=cmsy8
\font\sevensy=cmsy7
\font\preloaded=cmsy6
\font\fivesy=cmsy5
\font\tenex=cmex10
\font\preloaded=cmss10
\font\preloaded=cmssq8
\font\preloaded=cmssi10
\font\preloaded=cmssqi8
\font\tenbf=cmbx10
\font\preloaded=cmbx9
\font\preloaded=cmbx8
\font\sevenbf=cmbx7
\font\preloaded=cmbx6
\font\fivebf=cmbx5
\font\tentt=cmtt10
\font\preloaded=cmtt9
\font\preloaded=cmtt8
\font\preloaded=cmsltt10
\font\tensl=cmsl10
\font\preloaded=cmsl9
\font\preloaded=cmsl8
\font\tenit=cmti10
\font\preloaded=cmti9
\font\preloaded=cmti8
\font\preloaded=cmti7
\font\preloaded=cmu10
\font\preloaded=cmmib10
\font\preloaded=cmbsy10
\font\preloaded=cmcsc10
\font\preloaded=cmssbx10
\font\preloaded=cmdunh10
\font\preloaded=cmr7 at 14.51799pt
\font\preloaded=cmtt10 at 14.4pt
\font\preloaded=cmssbx10 at 14.4pt
\font\preloaded=manfnt
14787 words of font info for 50 preloaded fonts
14 hyphenation exceptions
Hyphenation trie of length 67065 has 2087 ops out of 35111
  475 for language 4
  475 for language 3
  478 for language 2
  478 for language 1
  181 for language 0
0 words of pdfTeX memory
0 indirect objects
No pages of output.
Transcript written on pdfetex.log.
fmtutil [INFO]: log file copied to: /Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdfetex.log
fmtutil [INFO]: /Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdfetex.fmt installed.
fmtutil [INFO]: --- remaking dvilualatex with luatex
fmtutil: running `luatex -ini   -jobname=dvilualatex -progname=dvilualatex dvilualatex.ini' ...
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019)  (INITEX)
 restricted system commands enabled.

(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/dvilual
atex.ini
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/lualate
x.ini
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/luatexc
onfig.tex
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/pdftexc
onfig.tex))
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx
(/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/texsys.cfg)
./texsys.aux found
```

Comment: try to force the format to be rebuilt with `fmtutil-sys --all` you have incompatible files with the input files updated to 2020 versions but using a 2018 latex, that can not work.

Comment: Have you tried the answer at the linked question, i.e. `fmtutil-sys --all`?

Comment: Thank you for you suggestions. Yes, I ran `fmtutil-sys -all`. No changes, I still get that error.

Comment: Hello @JKR! There are two of `-` before `all` (`--all`) in the suggested command above.

Comment: Can you post the (first 100 lines of the) output of `fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdflatex`? Use `sudo` if needed.

Comment: Thx, @Su-47, that was a typo

Comment: the log fragment you show is too truncated to really see the problem, but if you look in `/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx` what does it say around line 711, it should say `\edef\fmtversion
   {2020-02-02}
\def\patch@level{2}`

Comment: What do you get if you run `kpsewhich  -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt`?

Comment: Thx, @DavidCarlisle - it says `\edef\fmtversion   {2020-02-02} \def\patch@level{2}`

Comment: Thx @UlrikeFischer, it says `/Users/jrennstich/.TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`

Comment: And what does `kpsewhich --all -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` report?

Comment: then the format you are using isn't the format you made with fmtutil you must have a local one in the path somewhere

Comment: delete this and any other formats under /Users/jrennstich/.TinyTeX   : /Users/jrennstich/.TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - `/Users/jrennstich/.TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt
/Users/jrennstich/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - do you mean delete the entire folder content of /Users/jrennstich/.TinyTeX?

Comment: @JKR that may in fact be safe but I would never tell anyone to delete files without looking what is there, but you can delete any files with a `.fmt` extension

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, totally understood. Thanks. I deleted it, and reinstalled TinyTex.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help! It works again now! Thank you all so much - you saved my week!

Comment: Hmm. I don't know why or how the folder `/Users/jrennstich/.TinyTeX` was created in the first place. The only possible reason that I can think of is that when you install TinyTeX, you used `sudo` (e.g. `sudo R` and run `tinytex::install_tinytex()`), which you normally shouldn't use. If that's not the case, I'm totally confused. Anyway, glad to know it works now after you deleted this folder.

Comment: Thanks, @YihuiXie - no, I didn't run the install via `sudo` and the Termina. I always do it via `R`.

Comment: @JKR Okay. Thanks for letting me know!