# R Studio tinytex::tlmgr_update() gets an error

Tags: rstudio

When I try to run:

```
tinytex::tlmgr_update()
```

I get the following error:
[image]

Not sure what to do next, any advice?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you mean to write `tinytex::tlmgr_update()`? You missed `y` in `tinytex`.

Comment: I did, typo in question, just updated.

Comment: Also not sure if this is an ongoing issue https://github.com/edquant/edh7916/issues/26

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Compilation problem with fontenc-Latex - LaTeX2e problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/529413).

Comment: Thanks @Ross but did not unfortunately